# Using Facebook subscriptions for onetime payment

Tags: facebook, facebook-payments

I want to use subscriptions as a business model (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/subscriptions/) but for onetime payment (Upgrading from lite to full version). The problem is that the  metadata“fbpayment:billing_period” in fbpayment:subscription object takes "1 month" as default while the user in my app need to pay one time only to upgrade his version .
Also the subscription dialog shows the price of subscription per month which is not real in my case.
My aim for using subscriptions is to use Graph API for querying the subscription status and know who is already subscriber to give him access for specific materials . The regular payment follow in this tutorial: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/payments/paymentflow,  doesn't tell how to retrieval these records .

My question is that how to use subscriptions for onetime payment ?

Comment: I don't understand. Why do you wan to use subscriptions instead of just normal payments?

Comment: For querying for a user’s subscriptions, to know if he already subscriber . According to Facebook tutorail , this can be retrieved easy by using : GET https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/payment.subscriptions. While no information about how to know who is already purchased ( upgrade the app) with normal payments . Thank you

Comment: Just store it in your database if the user paid of not

Comment: Thank you WizKid, but if there is a way to use Facebook subscriptions API for onetime payment, then no need to create and maintain my own database